# Use jquery to make elements margin 0 on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, margin, fixed, sidebar

I have a navigation bar with a height 170px. Under this navigation bar is a fixed position sidebar. What i'm trying to do is get the sidebar which will start with a margin of 170px to have a 0margin after the user scrolls 170px; that way the sidebar looks like it gets caught by the top of the browser. Similar to the way instagrams titles work. What i want is actually exactly how the yellow sidebar on stack overflow's post "editor" works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$(document).bind('scroll',function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop <= 170) { $('#sidebar').css('top','170px'); }
    else {
        $('#sidebar').css('top',scrollTop+'px');
    }
});
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WqhDD/)